# Linq Expression Visitor to rewrite field from object Type A to object Type B where field is array on A and string on B

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

I have two objects:

```
class A
{
    public string FieldA;
    public string FieldB;
    public string[] FieldC;
}

class B
{
    public string FieldA;
    public string FieldB;
    public string FieldC;
}
```

I have this expression visitor class which rewrites a filter expression for fields fieldA and fieldB from object of **Type A** to object of **Type B**.

```
private class AtoBModelRewriterVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
         var lambda = (LambdaExpression)node;

         _LambdaStack.Push(
         lambda.Parameters.Select(parameter => objectAType == parameter.Type ? Expression.Parameter(objectBType) : parameter)
         .ToArray()
         );

         lambda = Expression.Lambda(
             this.Visit(lambda.Body),
             _LambdaStack.Pop()
         );

         return lambda;
    }
    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
         var memberExpression = (MemberExpression)node;

         var declaringType = memberExpression.Member.DeclaringType;
         var propertyName = memberExpression.Member.Name;

         if (objectAType == declaringType)
         {
             switch (propertyName)
             {
                 case "FieldA":
                 propertyName = "fieldA";
                 break;
                 case "FieldB":
                 propertyName = "fieldB";
                 break;              
             }

             memberExpression = Expression.Property(
                 this.Visit(memberExpression.Expression),
                 objectBType.GetProperty(propertyName)
             );
          }

          return memberExpression;
     }
     protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
     {
         node = (ParameterExpression)base.VisitParameter(node);
         if (objectAType == node.Type)
         {
             node = this._LambdaStack.Peek().Single(parameter => parameter.Type == objectBType);
         }
         return node;
     }

     #region [ Private ]

     private static Type objectAType = typeof(ObjectA);
     private static Type objectBType = typeof(ObjectB);
     private Stack<ParameterExpression[]> _LambdaStack = new Stack<ParameterExpression[]>();

     #endregion
 }
```

This works perfectly. Now I need to implement this for fieldC/FieldC, which is an array in objectA but a string in objectB, so I would need the expression to do something like:

```
objectB.fieldC.Contains(objectA.FieldC[0])
```

**OR**

```
objectB.fieldC.Contains(objectA.FieldC[N-1])
```

I am having a hard time writing this. I appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Define "having a hard time writing this." Do you not know where to begin, or are you seeing a specific error or behavior with the code that you've tried? I would think that it would involve using reflection to get the right generic signature of the `System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains<>()` method, and then using `Expression.Call()`, `Expression.MakeMemberAccess()`, `Expression.ArrayAccess`, and `Expression.Constant`.

Comment: Converting `Expression<Func<A, bool>>` to `Expression<Func<B, bool>>? Replacing `a.FieldC[...]` with `b.FiedC`?